# Changing d3.js symbol size based on the attribute of data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to scale the size of the symbols based on the value of an attribute 'WinsNoms' in the dataset. The chart is getting rendered and but it is not scaled according to 'winsNoms'. Could anyone help me where am I getting wrong?

```
var sizeExtent = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.WinsNoms });
var sizeScale = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain(sizeExtent)
                .range([5,15]);

var symbolTypesx = {
    "cross": d3.svg.symbol().type("cross").size(function(d) { return sizeScale(d.WinsNoms);}),
    "circle": d3.svg.symbol().type("circle").size(function(d) { return sizeScale(d.WinsNoms);})
};

svg2.selectAll("path")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    // position it, can't use x/y on path, so translate it
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
        return "translate("+xScale(d.imdbRating)+","+yScale(d.imdbVotes)+")"; 
    })
   .attr("d", function(d,i){
        if (d.IsGoodRating === 0)
        { // circle if bar === 0
            return symbolTypesx.circle();
        }
        else
        {
            return symbolTypesx.cross();
        }
    })
    // fill based on goo and foo
   .style("fill", function(d,i){
        if (d.IsGoodRating === 0)
                return "red";
            else
                return "blue";
    });
```

Comment: Your symbols declaration is in a variable named `symbolTypesx` but you then return the `d` attribute using a variable named `symbolTypes`...  Is this a typo?

Comment: Yes!! I corrected that but then I get this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'WinsNoms' of undefined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the datum into the symbol function when you call it:

```
return symbolTypesx.circle(d);
```

Running code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.17" data-semver="3.5.17" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
  
    var svg2 = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", 500)
      .attr("height", 500);
  
    var data = [{
      WinsNoms: Math.random(),
      GoodRathing: Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : 0
    }, {
      WinsNoms: Math.random(),
      GoodRathing: Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : 0
    }, {
      WinsNoms: Math.random(),
      GoodRathing: Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : 0
    }, {
      WinsNoms: Math.random(),
      GoodRathing: Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : 0
    }, {
      WinsNoms: Math.random(),
      GoodRathing: Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : 0
    }];

    var sizeExtent = d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.WinsNoms
    });
    var sizeScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain(sizeExtent)
      .range([5, 250]);

    var symbolTypesx = {
      "cross": d3.svg.symbol().type("cross").size(function(d) {
        return sizeScale(d.WinsNoms);
      }),
      "circle": d3.svg.symbol().type("circle").size(function(d) {
        return sizeScale(d.WinsNoms);
      })
    };

    svg2.selectAll("path")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .attr("transform", function(d,i) {
        return "translate(" + ((i * 20) + 10) + "," + ((i * 20) + 10) + ")";
      })
      .attr("d", function(d, i) {
        if (d.IsGoodRating === 0) { // circle if bar === 0
          return symbolTypesx.circle(d);
        } else {
          return symbolTypesx.cross(d);
        }
      });;
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```